# Как в Angular прочитать свою конфигурацию

Tags: веб-программирование, visual-studio, angular2

Допустим, приложение является оберткой над WebApi => его адрес может не совпадать с веб-мордой.

Я хотел описать сервисы для взаимодействия, но не хочется дублировать базовый адрес в каждом сервисе, ведь он может поменяться => правильно его вынести в конфигурационный файл.

Вроде, из JavaScript и TS нельзя читать файлы из файловой системы. Тогда, как я могу добиться решения своей задачи?

Думал создать базовый сервис, а в него вписать в виде константы базовый адрес и наследоваться от него, но по моему, если вдруг что-то поменяется, то придется перекомпилировать все приложение, что не есть гуд.

Comment: Его, адрес, можно отдавать как ресурс по фиксированному url, например..

Comment: есть же `environment` файлы

Comment: @overthesanity можно мини пример или ссылку где почитать?

Comment: [что-то вы совсем ленитесь читать документацию](https://angular.io/guide/build) 

Comment: @overthesanity Я могу ошибаться, но если вдруг придется что-то поменять в конфигурации, то придется перекомпилить все приложение?

Comment: смотря что вы имеете в виду под "перекомпилить"

Comment: Ну как я понимаю, придется перекомпилировать все TypeScript'ы, которые внутри себя используют данную константу, либо через какой-нибудь NotePad++ делать массовую замену в имеющихся JS-файлах.

Comment: если разные виды компиляции JIT и AOT, если это AOT - то вы не сможете делать массовую замену